# Dplyr backend is not able to find applicable method for 'sql_translate_env'

Tags: r, dplyr, monetdb

I try to run a simple dplyr command, on an monetdb SQL-backend. The connection itself seems to work, but the dplyr call fails. I restarted the RSession and tried to reinstall the `MonetDB.R` package again, without success.

```
library(dplyr)
db <- MonetDB.R::src_monetdb("ai_db", user="analyst", host="monetdb.local", password="mypassword")

## works!
DBI::dbGetQuery(db$con, "SELECT count(*) from users")

## fails
db %>% tbl("users") %>% mutate(n= n())
```

> Source:   query [?? x 7] Database: MonetDB 11.25.5 (Dec2016-SP1)
>
> Error in UseMethod("sql_translate_env") :    no applicable method for
>   'sql_translate_env' applied to an object of class "MonetDBConnection"

I installed dplyr using the default repository/settings (`packages.install("dplyr")`) in a docker container (rocker/verse:3.3.2).

**UPDATE 1: MonetDBLite instead od MonetDB.R**

Now I installed MonetDBLite and I use the following code to create a connection:

```
con <- mc(dbname="ai_db", user="analyst", password="mypassword", host="monetdb.local",
          timeout=86400000)
db <- MonetDBLite::src_monetdb("ai_db",con=con)
```

I set a quite high timeout, because of a error message indicating a to low one (see below). However, the command fails again and I don't think that it is related to the timeout, because it fails immediately.

```
## fails
db %>% tbl("users") %>% mutate(n= n())
```

> Source:   query [?? x 7] Database: MonetDB 11.25.5 (Dec2016-SP1)
>
> Error in .mapiRead(conObj@connenv$socket) :    Empty response from
>   MonetDB server, probably a timeout. You can increase the time to wait
>   for responses with the 'timeout' parameter to 'dbConnect()'.

The dataset is really small (just 5000 entries) so this should not be a big deal. MonetDB is installed ont he same server and works great, also the DBI interface works (and returns the result within a second):

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT count(*) from videos")
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Now I tried both, the dev-version of MonetdbLite and the stable CRAN-version from the repository. Both fail, but with different errors.

```
packages.install("MonetDBLite")
db <- MonetDBLite::src_monetdb("ai_db", user="analyst", password="mypassword", host="monetdb.local")
db %>% tbl("users") %>% mutate(n= n())
```

> Source:   query [?? x 7] Database: MonetDB 11.25.5 (Dec2016-SP1)
>
> Error in .mapiRead(conObj@connenv$socket) :    Empty response from
>   MonetDB server, probably a timeout. You can increase the time to wait
>   for responses with the 'timeout' parameter to 'dbConnect()'.

```
devtools::install_github( "hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite" )
db <- MonetDBLite::src_monetdb("ai_db", user="analyst", password="mypassword", host="monetdb.local")
db %>% tbl("users") %>% mutate(n= n())
```

> Source:   query [?? x 7] Error in inherits(con_acquire(x),
>   "MonetDBEmbeddedConnection") :    could not find function
>   "con_acquire"

Comment: hi, is that syntax correct?  https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html

Comment: passing test cases: https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite/blob/master/tests/testthat/test_03_dplyr.R  you might need  `devtools::install_github( "hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite" )` not sure

Comment: @AnthonyDamico I tried `src_monetdb("ai_db", user="analyst", password="mypassword", host="monetdb.local")`  first, but then I had to rewrite it to set the timeout (I always got this annoying timeout error). I will try to install the dev-version within the next days, but I hope that I get the stable CRAN version to work (I am using a pre-build docker image and I would prefer a solution without the need to install all the monetdb dependencies (e.g., `libmonetdb5.so`)).

Comment: @AnthonyDamico ok, it was not a dependency problem, I just had to set the permissions correctly and then I was able install the package using devtools. The newest version also fails, but with a different error (I updated my post already).

Comment: Do you mean the `ajdamico/lodown` library? should this fix the missing `con_acquire` function or the CRAN monetDBLite version? I installed it and tried the MonetdbLite devtools installation again, but I still get the same error (`could not find function "con_acquire"`)

Comment: i had linked to the wrong comment, sorry.  use `devtools::install_github("hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite",ref="fcb21f4c4223024922221d4ed1a8e78d647d8abe")`

Comment: oh thanks! But I think I found the problem. I used `src_monetdb("ai_db",...)` instead of `src_monetdb(dbname="ai_db",...)`. Now it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the MonetDBLite package instead, it contains the code to connect to standalone servers, too